# How to create sortable navigation items

Tags: php, class, recursion, navigation

I'm creating a site where the user should be able to change the order of navigation items. However, the navigation items are dynamically loaded from different sources and I do not know how many navigation items there are nor what items I can expect. All I know is that I have multiple files like this:

```
return array(
    array('Google', 'http://www.google.com'),
    array('StackOverflow', 'http://www.stackoverflow.com',
        array(
            array('Contact', 'contact.html'),
            array('Test', 'test.html')
        )
    ),
    array('Home', 'index.html')
);
```

As you can see this is a tree of menu items, with sub-items that can be any layer deep. All these arrays have to be combined into one navigation menu, and the files can change quite often. Clearly, this is not hard if the items do not have to be user-sortable. But with that functionality, I just can't come up with an efficient solution. Especially since I do not want to have the business logic and presentation mixed.

Currently, I have the following code (slightly simplified):

Controller:

```
$view = new \View('navigation.html');
$navigation = new mappers\Navigation();
$view->items = $navigation->fetchAll();
```

mapper\Navigation:

```
class Navigation {
    private $type;

    // Create a tree from:
    // $items: array(title, url, children); title = string; url = array / null / string; children = array / null
    // $order: url => array(position, children); position = integer; children = array / null
    // Pass $order by reference so that found items can be added
    private function buildTree($items, &$order) {
        $tree = array();

        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $uri = $item[1];

            // Get order
            if (isset($order[$uri])) {
                $position = $order[$uri][0];
                $childrenOrder = $order[$uri][1];
            } else {
                $order[$uri] = array(count($order), array()); // Create the item for this uri

                $position = $order[$uri][0];
                $childrenOrder = $order[$uri][1];
            }

            // Get children tree if specified
            if (isset($item[2])) {
                $children = $this->buildTree($item[2], $childrenOrder);
            } else {
                $children = null;
            }

            $tree[$position] = array($item[0], $uri, $children);
        }
        ksort($tree);   

        return $tree;
    }

    public function fetchAll() {
        $items = array();

        foreach (new \FilesystemIterator('navigation', \FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS) as $file) {
            if ($file->isDir()) { // Ignore everything which isn't a directory
                $array = new \PersistentArray($file->getPathname() . '/items.php');
                foreach ($array as $item) {
                    $items[] = $item;
                }
            }
        }

        // Load the order settings
        $order = new \PersistentArray('order.php');

        // Build a tree of all navigation items in the right order
        $tree = $this->buildTree($items, $order);

        Save the order settings (have been changed, since $order is passed by reference)
        $order->save();

        return $tree;
    }
}
```

navigation.html:

```
$echo = '';
$echo = function($item) use($echo) { // Use a closure, in order not to pollute the global namespace
    printf('<li><a href="%s">%s</a>', $item[1], $item[0]);
    if (!empty($item[2])) {
        printf('<ul>%s</ul>', $echo($item[2]));
    }
    echo '</li>';
}

?>

<ul>
    <?php foreach ($items as $item) {
        $echo($item);
    } ?>
</ul>
```

In this code `PersistentArray` is a simple class that loads an array from a file. Objects of this class are accessible like any array. They also provide a method `save()` which writes the array to a file. This file can later on be opened again using this class.

The above code works, but it does so in a way that looks pretty inefficient to me. I have four loops in this code! Not to mention that the reference and the closure are pretty "hacky". But I haven't been able to come up with a better way to solve this problem.

So my question is: can you come up with a better way to do this? Are there often-used methods? Thanks on forehand!

---

An example of a saved order array is:

```
return array(
    'index.html' => array(
        0 => 0,
        1 => array(
            'page1.html' => array(
                0 => 0,
                1 => array()
            ),
            'page2.html' => array(
                0 => 1,
                1 => array()
            )
        )
    ),
    'test.html' => array(
        0 => 1,
        1 => array()
    )
);
```

Comment: You first of all need a data-structure which can be re-used in the different layers of the applications. Provide recursive iteration onto that structure then you can decorate the iteration with sorting. Alternatively you can decorate the data-structure with sorting or add the sorting information to the data-structure already.

Comment: @hakre: Do you mean that I should for example create a `NavigationItem` class, a `NavigationParent` class, etc? And that I should create objects of those classes from the data? And that I should then sort those objects? But wouldn't that be even more inefficient?

What do you mean with "decorate the data-structure with sorting"? And isn't it true that I can't add the sorting information to the data-structure, unless I edit the navigation files?

Comment: Take the data-structure on a sheet of paper first, so no code is in your way. Where does the sort-order of the items come from? - *Edit:* - Also: As `$order` is an object, why do you pass it as reference?

Comment: @hakre: Indeed a stupid mistake to pass the object as a reference. As a matter of fact I've drawn out three versions of the data-structure on paper, and this is the best I've come up with. The order should be something that is editable from a user interface. So by default the items can be ordered randomly, but the user should be able to change the order of menu items. So it doesn't come from somewhere, it should only be possible to change it.

Comment: And how is the order specified? on item relative to the other (on the same level)? So each item could have a sort value and when two items are re-ordered, they swap these sort values. If you want to store sort different to the other data of the items, you need to map sort values to item values. It looks like you used the URL for it, you probably want to give each item a hash instead and encapsulate the hash calculation. The reference btw. is not causing concrete problems (at least as far I could see), but remove it. Also add the typehint to the parameter if you use it.

Comment: @hakre: The reference was there because I at first used a plain array. I can't use a typehint though, because `buildTree()` is also called for child items, and these do not have to be of type `PersistentArray`.

Clearly I would prefer to store the sort alongside the data, but I don't think there's a way to do that. That's the reason I came up with this solution. I will add an example of a saved order array to the question. The hash is a good idea!

But do you suggest I continue with this code, or try to come up with a better data structure? What do you think about this solution?

Comment: You are not far away, also for now you should keep your data-structure, using arrays to save that kind of information looks okay to me, an iterator can take care of the details later on. Why don't you make the third element the sort value and move children onto the fourth position?

Comment: What do you mean? And what do you mean with "An iterator can take care of the details later on"?

Comment: Well how you store the data is in the end pretty unimportant. Also how you will implement the structure in concrete, e.g. giving names, using one or multiple variables, classes or arrays. Important is that the data needed is there. An iterator is an object that know how to traverse the data-structure. It then can hide and deal with the logic of traversing and sorting the data. For example: http://php.net/class.recursivearrayiterator

Comment: Thanks for the link. Something I will have to look in to. But doesn't that just add even more overhead? This code is executed on every page load, and I'm already looping quite a lot. Or is this really necessary for the functionality I need?

Comment: Overhead? Normally not, Iterators help to reduce overhead by generalizing access onto structures. For example you can create an iterator that is only returning the items from those files from those directories of your case. Then use that iterator: `$items = iterator_to_array(new \DirectoryItemsIterator('navigation'));`

Comment: @hakre: Okay, that's clear. I'll look into that. Thanks a lot for all the help! Wish I could up-vote you!